# Javascript required to submit a form to a php script?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

What i currently have is a page that i am designing to edit info in a database. I know how to make the form in HTML and how to make the PHP script that stays on the sever. The proplem comes in with Javasrcipt. I have a tiny understanding of it. I have some javascript in this page already to make it dynamic but i'm stuck now at submiting the form back the php script.

The page must not move away from the where it is because it will make editing the info much easier that way. I have tried return false in the submit button with a edited script that i thouht would work but the submit button essentially become a dead button, doing nothing.

Heres a break down of my entire code. It gets confusing very quickly

```
<body>
<?php

$conn=odbc_connect("","","");
    if (!$conn)
      {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}

$sql="SELECT Artist.Artist, Artist.ID
FROM Artist
ORDER BY Artist.Artist";

$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs)
{exit("Error in SQL");}
```

This selects the artist so then a little piece of script then goes off a php page to get the albums for that artist and displays the next drop down for the albums to choose. The only info it is grabbing from this drop down is the id, and thats all it needs

```
echo "<form name='Artist'><select tabindex='1' name='Artist_list'     onchange='showUser(this.value)'>";
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
    $artist= odbc_result($rs,"Artist");
    $artist_id=odbc_result($rs,"ID");
echo "<option value='$artist_id'>$artist</option>";}
echo "</select>";
echo "</form>";
?>
<br />
```

This div is where the album drop down is

```
<div class="album" id="albumlist"><b>Album List</b></div>
<hr style=background-color="#e4a566"; color="#e4a566";/>
<br />
```

Then all the details like price cat no. and barcode are displayed here in a form along with tracklisting

```
<div class="album" id="albumdetails"><b>Album Details</b></div>

<br />
```

Album image gets displayed

```
<div class="imageforeditpage" id="image"><b>Image Goes Here</b></div>

<br />
```

This the page that must stay here forever, no matter what happens

From here is where i have proplems, i need the form with all the details to go to another php script that can then insert the changed data. I need all the info from id to tracklisting

This is the javascript that i use to get the id's to display my drop downs and details of album

```
function showDetails(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("albumdetails").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("albumdetails").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","albumdetails.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This is in the head of my document in a script tag.

I have searched the net flat and the answer has probably been staring at me but i have no clue how to put it into use.

I read something and have looked at document.form.submit but have no idea how to use it, if someone can help it would be much appriciated.

Just a side note this page will NEVER go live, it will be localhost and thats as far as it gets so anything thing that works will do, even jquery which i know even less

Any help including a tutorial pionting me to the direction will be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look into using a modern Javascript library like jQuery, as handling your Ajax across browsers yourself is not really what you want to be bothered with.
This page seems like a good example of how to handle what I think you're wanting to do:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: You are not really helping if you recommend a JS framework for every task. One just have to struggle a year or two with "native" JS programming to get original ideas and be able to boost their productivity with these frameworks. Else they just stuck if something does not go as expected as they would have no idea what something like `$.ajax()` really does.

Comment: the tutorail helped alot. I used it to get the understanding and now i can apply it to my own design. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id='yourformname' >

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.forms["yourformname"].submit();
</script>
```